# React return HTML with variable value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, concatenation

How I suppose to concatenate both `<i>` icon and phone number and return the value

```
phone = () =>{
     let mapvalue = this.props.mapvalue
     return <i class='fa fa-map-marker'></i> mapvalue  
}

render() {
    return (
      {this.phone()}
    )
}
```

Comment: Wrap it in a `span`? Like so: `return (<span><i class='fa fa-map-marker'></i>{ mapvalue }</span>);`.

Answer (score 0):

React.Fragment is only available on React v.16 or higher

```
render () {
  return (
     <React.Fragment>
       <i class='fa fa-map-marker'></i>{this.props.mapvalue}
     </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `<></>` if you are using React v.16.2+